# ng2-charts - set default configuration

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I'm trying to set default configuration with ng2-charts.

```js
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
        NgChartsModule.forRoot({
            defaults: {
              plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                  enabled: false, // => Type '{ enabled: false; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TooltipOptions<keyof ChartTypeRegistry>': external, position, xAlign, yAlign, and 36 more
                }
              }
            }
        }),
    ]
    ...
}
```

Problem is, it complains it's missing more than 30 properties on the type TooltipOptions.

I'm obviously not gonna set them all. Is there a default tooltip configuration option I can combine with? I'd like to do this:

```js
tooltip: {
    enabled: false,
    ...tooltipDefaultConfig
}
```

Same question goes for any option I'd like to override, where can I find default configs?

Answer (score 1):

I found out we can access default configurations like this:

```js
import {defaults} from 'chart.js';
```